# How to do a nonlinear optimization model in Pyomo with an integral in the objective function?

Tags: python, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, integral

I am attempting to solve a nonlinear dymanic optimization model (discrete time, finite horizon) with Pyomo. My model features two control variables and two state variables : the first one is experience that accumulates over time according to production, the second is an exhaustible resource that depletes according to production. Both transition equations for the state variables, as well as my objective function (total discounted production)

The integration is written as :

```
# Time horizon
model.T = pyo.RangeSet(0, 10)

# Range of ACAP
model.ACAP = pyodae.ContinuousSet(bounds = (.7, 1.7)) # Range of the integral
model.Phi = pyo.Var(model.ACAP, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals) # Used to integrate 

# Control variables
model.Tax = pyo.Var(model.T, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.Sub = pyo.Var(model.T, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds = (0. , 0.99))

# State variables
model.S = pyo.Var(model.T, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals) # Exhaustible resource
model.H = pyo.Var(model.T, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #Accumulated resource (experience)


#The function to be integrated : Phi is the integrated variable, while model.H is the current experience, that intervenes in the function
def to_be_integrated(model, ACAP,t):
    return ( (model.Phi[ACAP]*ω+(6*(model.H[t]**γ))) / ((model.H[t]**γ)+ω)) **(1/ρ) * truncpareto.pdf(model.Phi[ACAP], c = 1.7/.7, scale = .7, b = 2)

model.EAC = pyodae.Integral(model.ACAP, model.T, wrt = model.ACAP, rule = to_be_integrated)
```

This integral is the used in an intermediate function, called Zt (for readability), from which I derive the production function and the resource exhaustion :

```
def Zt(model,t) -> float:
    
    return ((5/(model.Tax[t]**α))**(1/ρ))+( model.EAc/((1-model.Sub[t])**(ν/ρ)))

# The production function
def Produce(model, t) -> float:

    return c1 * (Zt(model, t)**(ρ/(ρ+η)))

# Exhaustion of the resource, similar to the production function
def Edt(model, t) -> float:
    return c2 * Zt(model, t)**(-η/(ρ+η))*(5/(model.Tax[t]**(α+ρ)))**(1/ρ)
```

from there, I define my constraints and objective and solve :

```
# Update H with previous period production
def Gain_Exp(model, t) -> bool:
    if t == model.T.first():
        return model.H[t] == 5
    else :
        return model.H[t] == model.H[model.T.prev(t)] + Produce(model, t)

model.gain_Exp = pyo.Constraint(model.T, rule = Gain_Exp)

#Exhaust resource according to current production
def Deplete_resource(model : pyo.ConcreteModel, t : int) -> bool:
    if t == model.T.first():
        return model.S[t] == 280
    else : 
        return model.S[t] == model.H[model.T.prev(t)] + Edt(model.Tax[t], model.Sub[t], model.H[model.T.prev(t)])

model.gain_Exp = pyo.Constraint(model.T, rule = Deplete_resource)


# Objective function
def Objective(model : pyo.Model) -> float :
    return sum( 0.97**t * Produce(model.Tax[t], model.Sub[t], model.H[t]) for t in model.T)

model.Obj = pyo.Objective(rule = Objective, sense = pyo.maximize)

solver = pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
model.display()
```

Here are a few additional parameters to run the code :

```
p = 1                     
α = 0.036                    
ν =  0.27                   
η = 0.6                       
ρ = 1- α - η - ν            
ω = 300 ** 0.271                 
γ = 0.271                          
c1 = 29.819
c2 = 1.0735
```

However, the execution fails, with the following error :

```
PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (1.0  <=  1.4285714285714286*Phi[1.7]) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality. For example,
m.x = Var()
if m.x >= 1:
    pass
and
m.y = Var()
if m.y in [m.x, m.y]:
    pass
would both cause this exception.
```

I am running Python 3.10 under Spyder 5.4.3.

I also tried to define my integral using scipy.integrate.quad (which I understand much better than Pyomo.dae.Integral) however, I got another error (which led me to attempt to use Pyomo.dae.Integral instead):

```
TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo numeric value (((5.629646251607626 + 6*H[0]**0.271)/(H[0]**0.271 + 4.691371876339689))**10.638297872340429*0.6829185956790121) to float is disabled.
This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as arguments to
one of the Python built-in math module functions when defining
expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions or
explicitly resolving the numeric value using the Pyomo value() function.
```

I do not see how I can write my code with integrals. Do you see how I could proceed ?

Comment: caveat:  I don't use the integration functionality in pyomo, but...  You have a buried lookup function `truncpareto.pdf` in the formulation that isn't legal.  Also, several of your function calls appear incorrect...  You call `Produce(model, t)` with 3 arguments, which is an error, same with `Edt()`.  I suggest you edit your post to include **1 block of code which reproduces the error** you are experiencing after cleaning up the syntax errors.